# Java 8 stream fix Intermediate Stream methods should not be left unused sonar issue

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube, java-stream

```
 group.getTeamMemberIds().stream().filter(id -> userMap.containsKey(id)).
            map(id -> groupDTO.getTeamMembers().add(userMap.get(id)));
```

Sonar detects this as Intermediate Stream methods should not be left unused Major bug

Comment: well, that's half the information to seek a fix for it. yet a *terminal operation* is missing from your stream pipeline **without which the stream(intermediate operations like `map`) wouldn't be evaluated** either... so that's a uselessly written code currently... More details here https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: have you tested this one , with out terminal operator how this statement will executed ? can you provide more information ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no terminal operation here, thus this stream will not be executed; thus "unused" error by sonar.

You also have side effects in : `id -> groupDTO.getTeamMembers().add(userMap.get(id)`

there are better ways to solve this:

```
List<String> teamMembers = group.getTeamMemberIds() // I assume String here...
                      .stream()
                      .map(userMap::get)
                      .filter(Objects::notNull)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());


groupDTO.getTeamMembers().addAll(teamMembers);
```

You almost never need `containsKey` followed by `get` - you can avoid doing two hash lookups, by doing a `get` and see if result is not `null`

Comment: *You almost never need containsKey followed by get*: Except of course when working with a `Map` which allows `null` keys, may not be used often **but** can happen. Though in the context of this question it doesn't really makes sense to add a `null` team member

Comment: I now see, that's why you've written *almost never* so you probably thought of that :)

Comment: @Lino `HashMap` is the one I know allows this and it was seen as a design error - `Map::of`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, guava `ImmutableMap` and many more do not allow this